# Changing TextBox's Text in a ListView does not update ObservableCollection<string> Source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a quite complicated structure of ListViews. Inside this structure are TextBoxes with values from my ViewModel. When I change a value in some textbox, the property in ViewModel doesn't update. The "AllTexts" property in ViewModel still contains only "Hello" strings.

Basically, I want to show user structure of strings and then let the user change this structure. After he finishes his modification I want to save his changes. "Hello" strings are here just for testing.

**My ViewModel:**

```
class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>> AllTexts { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGroupIndex { get; set; }

        public int SelectedColumnIndex { get; set; }

        public ICommand AddGroup { get; private set; }

        public ICommand AddColumn { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            this.AllTexts = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>>();
            this.SelectedGroupIndex = -1;
            this.SelectedColumnIndex = -1;
            this.AddGroup = new Command(this.AddGroupCommandHandler);
            this.AddColumn = new Command(this.AddColumnCommandHandler);
        }

        private void AddGroupCommandHandler()
        {
            var tempColumn = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello" };
            var tempGroup = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();
            tempGroup.Add(tempColumn);
            this.AllTexts.Add(new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>(tempGroup));
        }

        private void AddColumnCommandHandler()
        {
           if (this.SelectedGroupIndex >= 0 && this.SelectedGroupIndex < this.AllTexts.Count)
           {
                var tempColumn = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello" };
                this.AllTexts[this.SelectedGroupIndex].Add(tempColumn);
           }
        }
    }
```

**My View:**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="vm" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllTexts, Source={StaticResource vm}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Background="Red"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedGroupIndex, Source={StaticResource vm}}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView
                        Background="Yellow"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedColumnIndex, Source={StaticResource vm}}">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListView
                                    Background="Green"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                     Width="100" Height="40"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>


        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Button Content="Add Group" Width="120" Height="30"
                Command="{Binding AddGroup, Source={StaticResource vm}}" />
            <Button Content="Add Column" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="120" Height="30"
                Command="{Binding AddColumn, Source={StaticResource vm}}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <TextBlock Width="120" Height="30" FontSize="20"
                Text="{Binding SelectedGroupIndex, Source={StaticResource vm}}" />
            <TextBlock Width="120" Height="30" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="20"
                Text="{Binding SelectedColumnIndex, Source={StaticResource vm}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Could someone, please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel has to notify the View about the changes, or else the View retains original values of the ViewModel

In this case, `string` cannot notify the changes made to itself. Only its enclosing observable collection can notify about **changes made to itself** like add or remove and does not monitor further into its elements.

So you need an observable string:

```
public class MyString : DependencyObject
{
    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyString), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

To use in the collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyString>>> AllTexts { get; set; }
```

---

I also added the following line to the `MyString` class in order to test the code and it worked.

```
public static MyString Hello { get { return new MyString { Value = "Hello" }; } }
```

Obviously, this is how it will be used:

```
 var tempColumn = new ObservableCollection<MyString>() { MyString.Hello, MyString.Hello, MyString.Hello, MyString.Hello, MyString.Hello };
```

---

In xaml there are also some unnecessary things which you can get rid of:

use `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` for both `ListView`s, and use `Text="{Binding Value}"` for the `TextBox`. (there is no need for explicit `TwoWay` in any of those)

Comment: @TomasGoffa you're welcome :) But don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and if you liked the answer you can vote-up too.